# Plot 3D line plot with breaks

Tags: python, matplotlib, line-plot, matplotlib-3d

I have three arrays formed by following lines:

```
x = np.tile(np.arange(0,200), 14)
y = np.random.randint(200, size=2800)
z = np.repeat(np.arange(1,15), 200)
```

and I use the following code to have 3D plot:

```
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot3D(x, z, y)
```

The resulting plot looks like this:
[image]

But here you can see there are lines connecting in the middle. how can I introduce breaks in the middle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You don't want to plot a single curve, you want to plot 14 different curves,
the `x` is always the same, the `z` is *almost* the same, what is really changing is the `y`'s.

So I'd suggest to use the same `x`, the same `z` and a `ys` array, shaped `(14, 200)` and have an enumerated loop on `ys`'s rows, as follows

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
x = np.arange(0,200)
ys = np.sin(x*(0.4+0.6*np.random.rand(14))[:,None]/10)
z = np.ones(200)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection":"3d"})
for n, y in enumerate(ys): 
    ax.plot3D(x, z+n, y, color=['blue', 'red'][n%2])
```